# App Script Google Classroom API adding teachers to a course via batch press (loop)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-classroom

```js
function testScripts() {
  var courses = [12345678902, 123425373134];
    
  var newTeacher = ["teacher@mail.com", "teacher@mail.com"];
    
  for (x = 0; x <= courses.length - 1; x++) {
    var final = courses[x];
    var finalT = newTeacher[x];
    
    var addTeacher = Classroom.Courses.Teachers.create(
      { userId: finalT }, final
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried this code but it gives me this error: `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to classroom.courses.teachers.create failed with error: Requested entity already exists`

Only the first course in the array is updated with the new teacher to be added.

Thank you!

Comment: You might want consider taking a JavaScript course online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var courses = [12345678902, 123425373134];
    
var newTeacher = ["teacher@mail.com", "teacher@mail.com"];

for (x = 0; x <= courses.length - 1; x++) {
  Classroom.Courses.Teachers.create(
    {userId: newTeacher[x]}, courses[x]
  );
}
```

solved it. directed it to the declared variable above.